# What is this equation formally?

Tags: exponentiation

*Having fun with the calculator, I realized that :*

`(a^c)` and `(a^b)`

with `c > b` and `c > 4` and `b = 2`

```
a^c / a^b = a^(c-2)
```

***So, for example:***

`3^5 / 3^2 = 27` is ***same that*** `3^(5-2) => 27`

**I know it's basic, but how is this happening?**

**What is this formally called? I realized thinking "How often is this greater than this other"**

*I think it's "exponential growth"*

Comment: A beautiful isomorphism between $\langle \Bbb R,+ \rangle$ and $\langle \Bbb R_{>0}, \cdot \rangle$.

Comment: Assuming $c>b$,$$\frac{a^c}{a^b}=\frac{\overbrace{a\times\dots\times a}^c}{\underbrace{a\times\dots\times a}_b}=\overbrace{a\times\dots\times a}^{c-b}=a^{c-b}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Congrats, you discovered the rule of division with powers:

$$ \frac{b^m}{b^n} = b^{m-n} $$

Comment: Oh, I suppose that's how intellectuals thought in antiquity

Answer (score 0):

A fraction with five factors equal to $3$ in the numerator, and two factors $3$ can be simplified by the elementary rules on fractions.